# Placing a variable-width, float:right span of images inside an input

Tags: html, css

I have a payment card number input field and want card icons to display inside the input on the right side.  With nothing in the field, I want three icons to display, but when the user types a value, I am programmatically removing two of the icons.  Whatever icon(s) show, 1 or 3, I want them to stay justified on the right side of the input.  While I can line things up and use float:right to put the images on the right side, they are always behind the input.  If I try to use position:absolute, they won't float:right.

Here's a stripped-down example.  The margin-top on cardImages is just so you can see the images (or broken image icons) are hiding there behind the input.

```
<html>
<style>
  .container {
      width:20rem;
      white-space:nowrap;
  }
  .cardImages {
      float:right;
      margin-top:.6rem;
  }
  .cardInput {
      width:20rem;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <span class="cardImages">
      <img src="card_visa.svg">
      <img src="card_mastercard.svg">
      <img src="card_discover.svg">
    </span>
    <input class="cardInput" type="number">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The only other thing I can think to do is to create two different spans, one with all three images, and one with just one, and I could programmatically show the appropriate span and if I show the latter, I can also put the right icon in it.  The only problem with this (apart from extra code) is I'd theoretically like to do some transition affects to move the icons around as the user types.

Any clever CSS tricks would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can unstyle the input, give the outer container a border (letting the viewer think that's the input border, and simplify the elements disposition a lot by just placing them inline one after the other, like this:

```
<html>
<style>
  .container {
      width: calc(20rem + 5rem);
      height: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #777;
  }
  .cardImages {
    width: 5rem;
  }
  input {
      width:20rem;
      appearance: none !important;
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    border: none;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <input class="cardInput" type="number">
      <span class="cardImages">
        <img src="card_visa.svg">
        <img src="card_mastercard.svg">
        <img src="card_discover.svg">
      </span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a unique and interesting way to solve the issue as stated that I certainly didn't think of, and I appreciate the thought that went into it.  Unfortunately the actual code I'm working with is highly-styled Angular components, not straight HTML, and I can't easily strip off and re-add borders without a lot of fallout.  I was just hoping there was some combination of display and/or position attributes that I could apply to the internal elements that would put the img above the input.

Answer (score 0):

My current, brute force solution is to move back to a left-aligned display and programmatically change the margin to move the icons to the right side of the input when performing the hide.  I'd love a more elegant solution, but this works for now.

```
<html>
<style>
  .container {
      white-space:nowrap;
  }
  .cardImages {
    margin-left:-4rem;
  }
  .cardInput {
    padding-right:4rem;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <input class="cardInput" type="number">
    <span class="cardImages">
      <img src="card_visa.svg">
      <img src="card_mastercard.svg">
      <img src="card_discover.svg">
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

programmatically set .cardImages margin-left to 1.5rem when hiding two icons.